# Break Page Content letter use less then sign

Tags: javascript, c#

`When I use less then Sign in print Content letter and click for print then page will be break after use less then sign.

Example:- I am a < boy .
Output is :- I am a `

`data = data.replace(new RegExp("&lt;", "g"), '&amp;lt;');`

Comment: Please read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints - at the moment it's *entirely* unclear what the context is for this question. How is this question relevant to both C# and Javascript?